# How to have multiple Firebase AddSnapshotListener(s) inside a single class?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I have a class in android which has a listener setup to get visitorlist updates.

```
var visitorDetailsCollection = FirebaseFirestore.Instance.Collection("visitorDetails");
            var visitorDetailsquery = visitorDetailsCollection.WhereEqualTo("UserID", Firebase.Auth.FirebaseAuth.Instance.CurrentUser.Uid);
            visitorlistner = visitorDetailsquery.AddSnapshotListener(this);
```

and when the firestore db is updated the following method runs and gets the updates

```
 public void OnEvent(Java.Lang.Object obj, FirebaseFirestoreException error)
{
try
            {
                var docs = (QuerySnapshot)obj;
                visitorDetails.Clear();
                foreach (var doc in docs.Documents)
                {
                        var visitordetails = new VisitorDetails
                        {
                            Name = doc.Get("VisitorName").ToString(),
                            ContactNumber = doc.Get("VisitorContact").ToString(),
                            VehicleNumber = doc.Get("VisitorVehicleNo").ToString(),
                            IsApproved = doc.Get("VisitorIsApproved").ToString(),
                            IsActive = doc.Get("VisitorIsActive").ToString(),
                            Purpose = doc.Get("PurposeOfVisit").ToString(),
                            Email = doc.Get("VisitorEmail").ToString(),
                            FromDate = toDatetime(doc.GetDate("FromDate") as Date),
                            ToDate = toDatetime(doc.GetDate("ToDate") as Date),
                            docID = doc.Id
                        };
                        visitorDetails.Add(visitordetails);                   
}
```

Now I want to add another listener to get residentdetails like this

```
residentlistner = residentDetailsquery.AddSnapshotListener(this);
```

How do I tell this listener to run a different function like

```
public void OnEvent2(Java.Lang.Object obj, FirebaseFirestoreException error)
{}
```

when the firestore db is updated?

Comment: don't use `this`.  Instead create separate instances of the listener (or instances of different listeners)

Comment: Hi Jason, how to do that?

Comment: This solution worked like a charm https://csharpforums.net/threads/how-to-have-multiple-firebase-addsnapshotlistener-s-inside-a-single-class.8100/post-30109